# for loop is locking thread

Tags: java

I expect the following code to print out text forever:

```
Thread t = new Thread()
{

    public void run()
    {

    for(;;)
        {
            System.out.print("thread  example");
        }
    }
};


t.start();
```

But it does not . It just locks up because of the for loop. Can someone tell me why ?

Comment: `System.out` is line-buffered, you'll need some newline characters before anything will display.

Comment: Your example code works for me

Answer (score 5):

`print` doesn't flush the buffer -- you want `println`, which puts in a newline and does flush the buffer.

Essentially, you *are* printing a bunch, but you're printing to an in-memory buffer, so you don't see it.

Comment: That does not seem to be true, check out the docs:  
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

Comment: @Selim What part of the docs contradict it? `PrintStream::print(String)` says it writes its bytes like `write(int)`, and [that method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write-int-) says it flushes "byte is a newline and automatic flushing is enabled."

Comment: You're right, I didn't see that part (`write(int)`). However the example works perfectly for me.

Comment: It works for me, too, actually -- the buffer is filling up and flushing on its own. It could be system-dependent as far as how much (and to where) it's buffering, or maybe there's some other bug the OP isn't seeing.